# Subdividing gives me too much vertices

Tags: modeling, modifiers, export

So I have a 3d model and Before exporting I have to applied the modifier but there are too much vertices after applying the subdivided modifier. So is there a was to apply the subdivide modifier but not changing the number of vertices

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: You don't necessarily have to apply the modifier and you can reduce the number of subdivisions to 1. The real question is: Why do you want to apply the modifier and what is the goal you're trying to achieve? Based on that we'll be able to recommend an approach.

Comment: Well I want to export it to maya and I think I can't eport it without putting the modifier. And I cant subdivide only once because the lines and the model isn't clear enough.

Comment: I've just seen the edit to your question. You can't apply the subdivide modifier without adding vertices, since that is the very purpose of the modifier. Either the geometry needs to be edited or you could create a normal map from the high poly which you can apply onto the lower poly version?

Comment: how to I apply a normal map ?

Comment: If the low-poly is too low-poly, don't you have a kind of Subsurf modifier in Maya, so you wouldn't have to apply it in Blender?

Comment: I will checks if there is one